# Problems related to symmetry

Tags: reference-request, dihedral-groups

I am currently studying the chapter entitled "Symmetry" from Michael Artin's book "Algebra" and am having some difficulties understanding the material. It is dealing with isometries, dihedral groups, ...

Would anybody recommend any other book for the lesson and somewhere were I can find problems to train on.

I am open for English and French books.

Comment: Michael Artin's  book would probably be the best one on the subject, while being concise.  What concepts are you having trouble with?  I have the book.  If you need to search for another book there's http://carlossicoli.free.fr/  and http://bookos.org, which would allow you to review the book before buying.

Comment: @EnjoysMath It is not a good book. Very concise. Not enough problems.

Comment: Any other propositions ?